# selection group

Tags: objects, groups, select

Imagine I have 10 objects in my scene.

I keep needing to select object 1,6 and 9 to do something.

Is there a way to name this group? Say 169.

I dont want to group/parent/put in container. This "group" is for selecting only.

So every time I want to select object 1,6 & 9, I can just select the group called 169.

Does that make sense and can it be done?

Comment: it can be done via python script. The question is: why don't you want to use parent/container, because these are the obvious ways to do such things in blender? What you also could think about is joining these 3 objects...you can later separate them if needed.

Comment: In the Machin3TOOLS addon there is a group function, it parents the group to an empty, then you can select the whole group by holding `shift` and `double-left-click` on one of the objects

Comment: I do use and know about groups, parenting and joining but this is slightly different (correct me if I'm wrong).  In my scene, I have groups, containers and parented hierarchies. 

Imagine I have a complex octopus rig (so hierarchy bones and controllers). Say, I want to sometimes move 8 arms at once. I could sent up an empty for this but I would need lots of empties for all the other combinations of arms.

Surely, a simpler method is to get Blender to "remember" the selected objects and put it into a "selection group" list?

Comment: You probably miss that Autodesk 3ds Max feature as much as I do !